# Eclipse : can not find the tag directory

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, eclipse-juno

---

Hi ,

i'm getting this error "the can not find the tag directory "/WEB-INF/tags"" but i'm sure that the directory (/WEB-INF/tag) exists under the root project.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="squash" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org     
 /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>

 <head>

</head>

  <body>

<div id="content">
    <h1><fmt:message key="welcome"/></h1>
</div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What version of *eclipse*? Have you include *standard.jar* and *jstl.jar* in build path?

Comment: eclipse juno but i didn't add jstl.jar and standard.jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include/add standard.jar and jstl.jar (or simply add http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar - no need to include standard.jar ) to your web-project via:

1. Right mouse click on project name at Project Explorer
2. Build Path + Configure Build Path + Libraries + Add External Jars + Select the downloaded jstl.jar and standard.jar (If you've installed `tomcat` then you will find these .jars at X:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.22\webapps\examples\WEB-INF\lib) folder.

PS: For further information read -  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info